# Validate video timestamp format

Tags: javascript, validation, video, timestamp

I'm currently working on a textarea comment where users can post specific timestamp for a video on the same page. The format would be **@minute:seconds**.

If valid, I will store the comment and wrap the timestamp as a link so it can be clicked and move the video to the specific timestamp.

For example, @6:23 will be stored as 
[@6:23](http://#) (similar to youtube).

How would I write a validation script to check first for '@', then minutes (i.e. '06', '6', '126), followed by a ':', and then seconds (i.e. '01', '32', '59')?

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a regular expression test:

```
if( /(^@\d\d:\d\d)/.test(input) ){
    alert(input+" Is Valid!");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rmullins/dq3gx2jr/

Comment: That's close, but it something like: **4:15** does not validate, and something like **04:159** does, which is wrong. Seconds has to be 2 numeric digits only. Acceptable formats should be: **4:15**, **04:15**, or **124:15** (2 hours, 4 minutes, and 15 seconds). Thanks!